# Code Igniter Returning Blank Page

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm using Code Igniter 3.0. My code is running properly but when I insert the query code, it suddenly returning blank page.When I run inspect element, it show error 500 GET method. Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class main extends CI_Controller{    
    function index(){       
        $this->load->view('testjs2');}}
```

Here's the view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testjs</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('css/half-slider.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="<?php echo base_url('css/sb-admin.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
test
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped" id="dataTables-example2">
        <thead>
            <tr class="info">
            <th >no matrik</th>
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th >Email</style></th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php  
        echo 'testlagi';    
        //$this->load->database();        
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM wifiview_stsdaftar'); 
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            //$j= $row->NOMATRIK;
            ?>
            <tr>  
            <td><?php echo $row->NOMATRIK;?></td>          
            <td><?php echo $row->NAMA;?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->EMAIL;?></td>                              
            </tr>                               
            <?php
        } ?>  
    <table> 

</div> <!-- end of div container -->
```

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

See naming convention

```
class main extends CI_Controller{  
      ^// m should be capital letter

class Main extends CI_Controller{
```

Class name should start with capital letter, so does the file name of the `controllers`, `models` and `libraries`.

See codeigniter 3 [style guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html) for more information(specifically [`File Naming`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming) and [`Class and Method Naming`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming))

Answer (score 0):

Hello i believe you forgot to load the model .This is a common mistake .

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

please try it